# "tap on the button" vs "tap the button"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I am trying to figure out which term to use when writing a "help text" or giving messages to the user on an app.

Should I say:

- tap the button  OR
- tap on the button
- tap the item  OR
- tap on the item
- tap the word  OR
- tap on the word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either is acceptable.  The first, however, is simpler; in this case, the 'on' is understood, and therefore redundant.  Someone would normally tap *on* an icon, word, link, etc., unless there was a reason they would expect to be tapping above, or below, or beside it.  In this case, since a tap of an element is normally understood to be a tap *on* the element, the extra word is redundant.

Comment: Bear in mind that **to tap** can also signify either **to draw liquid from** or **to exploit a resource** . So to tap someone's head and to tap someone's brains are not the same thing. Nor are tapping a barrel and tapping on a barrel.    https://www.google.com/search?q=to+tap&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: True.  Context here, though, is computing/app development.  In that context, tap/tap on would be understood identically.

Comment: Agreed that it is probably obvious, but it's still worth pointing out.  Someone could be working on a beer-themed lifestyle app where "tap the barrel" might be ambiguous to some of the target audience.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above options are fine - omitting 'on' is more concise though.